# Label with two ids in the for attribute

Tags: html, attributes, label

Can a label have two ids inside the `for` attribute? I have only one input in the page, which has either `id1` or `id2` depending on an `if` clause.

I would like to have something like this:

```
<label value="someLabel" for="id1 id2"/>

if(condition)
<input type="text" name="input1" id="id1"/>
else
<input type="text" name="input2" id="id2"/>
fi
```

Comment: Use if condition to render both label and input as label's for attribute only hold one id value.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it like this instead:

```
if(condition)
    <label value="someLabel" for="id1"/>
    <input type="text" name="input1" id="id1"/>
else
    <label value="someLabel" for="id2"/>
    <input type="text" name="input2" id="id2"/>
end
```

Comment: There is not only a label there so I would have to repeat a lot of HTML code in the IF statement.